# Swift: How to make Push Notification open to specific tab on tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iOS 8 app written using swift. 
My app has a tab bar controller with 4 tabs , one of which is the "Notifications" tab.

I am using Parse to send push notifications. When the user opens a push notification from the Home/Lock screen I want it to open to the "Notifications" tab

I haven't been able to find any tutorials or questions in swift to help here. Can someone explain how to accomplish this?

I have this in my AppDelegate but It didnt work:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
let tab :CustomTabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as CustomTabBarController
tab.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Changing the selected index doesn't automatically change the displayed view controller. Use the `selectedViewController:` method instead. This *will* update the selected index on the tab bar as well. See [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController).

Example:

```
tab.selectedViewController = tab.viewControllers[1]
```

Comment: I added this but it had no effect on opening a notification.